# Processing circle in webpages

Tags: javascript, html

In Most of the web sites we see the common one 'Processing cricle' for indicating page loading /image loading etc.. and making the main(parent ,back) page faded..  I would like to know what are those concepts and how could I implement those

Comment: I'd recommend you change your tag from "java" to "javascript" unless you are referring to the actual programming language "Java". From your question it seems you are asking a "javascript" related question.

Answer (score 2):

The circle probably indicates that there is a pending AJAX call.

Have a look at the [AJAX Tutorial at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) for an introduction.

The "loading animations" can be generated at http://ajaxload.info/

Answer (score 0):

@aioobe has a good answer, but as you didn't provide any example pages, I'll offer other reasons for `progress indicators`:

- Ajax calls may be in progress
- Very long page loads can use an animated gif during the load before the load event has fired
- Flash content may be loading (similar to AJAX as it's an asynchronous HTTP request)
- multi-threaded JavaScript may be executing.

Each situation has its own implementation, and you may want to either ask a new question in regard to each method, or turn this question into a community wiki.